# How to get SAS tables sizes and last usage time in library

Tags: sas, radix

Good day!

I need a list of libraries-tables on a SAS server with a size of each table and last time, when it was open/used.

I'm not very familiar with SAS, so I don't even know where would I start searching :(

I assume, that there is some simple solution, maybe a proc of some sort, that may help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `proc contents` to access metadata about a library in SAS, for example using the `sashelp` library:

```
proc contents data = sashelp._ALL_ NODS;
run;
```

`sashelp` is the library you are refencing. By specifying `_ALL_` you ask SAS for data about all the files in this library (by choosing a singular file such as `sashelp.ztc` you can get information on jut one file).

This will give you a lot of information, so by using the `NODS` statement you can suppress the output to give you less detail. The above code will give you the number of files, their type, the level, the file size, and the data they were last modified.

If you want to output this information to a dataset, you have to use the ODS output system with the correct ods table name, in this case it is `Members`. Furthermore, if you're looking for datasets in particular then you can filter the output with a `where=` statement:

```
ods output Members = test (where = (memtype = "DATA"));
proc contents data = work._ALL_ NODS noprint;
run;
ods listing; /* change back to listing output*/
```

Comment: This would get you info on dataset size and creation date and lots of other good stuff, but I don't think it gives you the last time the dataset was read, does it?  If it's a metadata library, it's possible that might be in some metadata somewhere?

Comment: It's right, there is no information about last entry time, but most likely I was mistaken about possibility to gather this kind of information.
But allright, creation/modification date seems enough.